# how can i copy the variable in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, copy

```
IEnumerator reload()
    {
        if (total_bullet >= start_bullet)
        {
            firable = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadtime);
            currentbullet = 0 + start_bullet;
            total_bullet -= start_bullet;
            firable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            firable = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadtime);
            currentbullet = 0 + total_bullet;
            total_bullet -= total_bullet;
            firable = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the reloading code for my game. And after that, I decrease current bullet every time I shoot.
But after reloading, sometimes **total_bullet** decreases instead and sometimes it doesn't. I think I need to copy the variable but is it the right solution? And if it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One guess is; the previous coroutine may not be ending before you start another one and it might be messing things up.

Try assigning your coroutine to a variable and stop the coroutine before you call it again.

Something like:

```
//Put this at the definitions part of your code.
Coroutine coReload;

//This is for the function where you call your reload() function.
if (coReload != null)
{
    StopCoroutine(coReload);
}
coReload = StartCoroutine(reload());
```

Otherwise it would be helpful to know more about your code.

Comment: Might want to specify what 'the post above' is. Things get reshuffled over time on here and it will be very hard for someone to understand what you are talking about in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your code the only reason I can find for not decreasing `total_bullet` is when `start_bullet` is zero.

Comment: then i guess we need to know more about the class contain this method and it's fields. Personally i would start with adding some console.log's just to get a better understanding of what''s going on.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `total_bullet -= total_bullet;` makes the **total_bullet** value equal to 0, so you can set the variable directly to 0.

```
 IEnumerator reload()
 {
     firable = false;
     if (total_bullet >= start_bullet)
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadtime);
         currentbullet = 0 + start_bullet;
         total_bullet -= start_bullet;
         firable = true;
     }
     else
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadtime);
         currentbullet = 0 + total_bullet;
         total_bullet = 0;
         firable = true;
     }        
 }
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue tough does it?